# If $X$ is a random variable, under which conditions is $g(X)$ also a r.v.?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, random-variables

In many instances, functions of random variables appear, and we usually treat them as random variables also. In the 3d edition, pp. 85-86, of [this well-known book](http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/electrical/papoulis/) (now in its 4th edition), we find the following (the book uses $\mathbf x$ to denote the random variable - I use $X$):
Let $X$ be a (real) random variable (the author does not seem to make any distinction between continuous and discrete r.v.'s). Define $Y = g(X)$. For it to also be a random variable the following must hold (and I quote):

> 1. Its domain must include the range of $X$.
> 2. It must be a "Baire function", that is, for every $y$, the set $R_y$ such that 
>      $g(x) \le y$ must consist of the union and intersection of a countable number of 
>      intervals. Only then $\{Y \le y\}$ is an event.
> 3. The events $\{g(X) = \pm \infty\}$ must have zero probability.

The 1st condition *looks* self-evident, more part of the definition of $g(X)$ rather than a condition.

Regarding the 2nd condition, I don't really have the feeling of how large or small a class is the Baire functions. I just note that since a random variable is a function too, then $X$ should be a Baire function also.

The 3d condition is interesting because, for example, it *appears* to ban from the class of random variables the reciprocal of a Bernouli r.v. (since the author uses the $\infty$ symbol in the RHS of an equality, I took the freedom to contemplate division by zero... or perhaps this condition restricts us to the class of continuous r.v.'s where we can treat $\infty$ as the result of a limiting operation?).  Earlier in the book (p. 66) this condition is also stated as a condition in order for $X$ itself to be considered a random variable.

I don't think I have the necessary knowledge to argue with these conditions, but somehow the ensemble seems...unsatisfactory -not "interconnected" perhaps. So my questions are:

1) If these are indeed the conditions for $Y = g(X)$ to be a random variable, how safe is to assume that "in most" cases they are satisfied, and so we can "freely" treat the frequent $g(X)$ expression as a random variable?

2) Is there perhaps some other way to restate these conditions?

3) Is there an objection to them, or something that is missing?

*(I understand that we are supposed to ask only one question at a time, but clearly these three are essentially one call:"please provide feedback on the stated conditions").*

Comment: ...you just need $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be measurable, with respect the the $\sigma$-algebra in your definition of random variable. I would suggest staying as far away as possible from those three "conditions".

Comment: @Michael I like this firm statement! -but I think that a book that has been used to teach possibly tens of thousands of people, mainly in the filed of electrical engineering, at least from what I read (I am not one of them), must be challenged in a more elaborate manner...

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate Professor Sarwate, perhaps you could help with this question?

Comment: To see such refinements in a book for electrical engineers is truly bewildering. FWIW, I had never seen Condition 2. before (Conditions 1. and 3. being of a different nature, and basically trivial). Tens of thousands of students notwithstanding, this paragraph might be one of the most bizarre teaching choices ever made. Like @Michael said, just drop the thing.

Comment: @Did Thanks Did. Snooping around I found that Baire sets are related to $\sigma$-algebras and Borel sets, whence perhaps the choice of the author to use the Baire concept. He has passed away, otherwise I would have attempted to ask him directly.